# Creating dataframes from others

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to filter multiple data frames and create new data frames based on them. 
The multiple data frames are called as `df[str(i)]`, i.e. `df["0"]`, `df["1"]`, and so on.

I would need, after filtering the rows, to create new dataframes. I am trying as follows:

```
n=5
for i in range(0, n):
   filtered = df[str(i)]
```

but it returns at the end only the latest dataframe created, i.e. `n=5`. 
I have tried also with `filtered[str(i)]` but it gives me the error `"n"`.

What I would like to have is:

```
filtered["0"] for df["0"]
filtered["1"] for df["1"]
...
```

I would appreciate your help to figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could append your filtered dataframes to a list, then concatenate into a new dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
n=5
dfs = []
for i in range(n):
   filtered = df[str(i)]
   dfs.append(filtered)

df_filtered = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: Thank Rcameron. How could I call a single filtered dataframe? I would prefer to keep the same format because it is easier to manage. I would like to have multiple dataframes, not only one.

Comment: Oh, I see, so the issue is that you want not to end up with a single dataframe at the end but with many dataframes?  In the above solution, ```dfs``` is a list of the filtered dataframes, any one of which you can access via dfs[0], dfs[1], etc.